# Compute $\nabla_{\alpha '} V$ in local coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a surface $S \subset \mathbb R^3$ and a curve $\alpha \subset S$. Let $V$ be a vector field defined along $\alpha $.

Write $$\begin{aligned}\alpha &=(u^1(t), u^2(t)) ,\\
 \alpha '(t) &= \frac{du^1}{dt} \partial_1 + \frac{du^2}{dt} \partial_2 ,\\
V(t) & = v^1(t) \partial_1 + v^2(t) \partial_2
\end{aligned}$$

Then $$\begin{aligned}\nabla_{\alpha '} V & = \frac{du^i}{dt}(\partial_i v^j)\partial_j + \frac{du^i}{dt} v^j \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial _k \\
& = (\frac{d}{dt} v^k + \frac{du^i}{dt} \Gamma^k_{ij} v^j  ) \partial_k
\end{aligned}$$

My question is: how to get $$\frac{du^i}{dt}(\partial_i v^j)\partial_j = \frac{d}{dt} v^k \partial_k$$

Thank you!

Comment: Its by chain rule.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 I'm quite confused with these symbols, can you explain a little bit more? Thank you!

Comment: $\partial_i v^j = \frac{\partial v^j}{\partial u^i}$. So $$ \frac{du^i}{dt}\partial_i v^j = \frac{du^i}{dt} \frac{\partial v^j}{\partial u^i}  = \frac{dv^j}{dt}$$

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 Please, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552333/unclear-equation-with-partial-and-total-derivatives I couldn't reach you, my whisperer doesn't always your name.