# Unclear equation with partial and total derivatives

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds, curves

Suppose $M$ is a manifold and $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function. Also let $\alpha :I\to \mathbb{R}^n$be a representation of a curve and $(\phi,U)$  be a chart. Now why it holds that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\alpha}=\frac{d(f\circ \gamma)}{dt}$$
?

Here, $\gamma(t)=\phi^{-1}\circ\alpha(t).$

Comment: Whats the expression in the LHS ? I think its incomplete.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 It is the $\alpha$-th coordinate curve where $x^{\alpha}(\gamma(t))=t+const$

Comment: I'm sorry but i cant understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 Oh, sorry. Fixed now.$\partial$ was missing there.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 Is it OK now?I've added one line below the question.